# How to enable Windows Authentication with in-process IIS hosting under IdentityServer4?

Tags: iis, identityserver4, windows-authentication

My ASP.Net Core MVC app accesses a .Net Core API through IdentityServer. It works fine on IIS server running in-process with Entity Framework based identity store. Now I am trying to enable Windows Authentication and getting stuck here.

What I tried is following the identityserver doc section "Windows Authentication" - I added the code below to the ConfigureServices of my IdentityServer's Startup.cs

```
    // configures IIS in-proc settings
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
    {
        iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
        iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });
```

I also enabled the Windows Authentication in IIS for my API app

[image]

The part of the doc that I am confused about is "You trigger Windows authentication by calling ChallengeAsync on the Windows scheme". It doesn't mention where you do that. I am assuming it is in identityserver and I put the code in the Login method of the AccountController of the identityserver as bellow.

```
/// <summary>
/// Entry point into the login workflow
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    // trigger Windows authentication by calling ChallengeAsync
    await ChallengeWindowsAsync(returnUrl);

    // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
    var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

    if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
    {
        // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
        return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", new { scheme = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
    }

    return View(vm);
}

private async Task<IActionResult> ChallengeWindowsAsync(string returnUrl)
{
    // see if windows auth has already been requested and succeeded
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Windows");
    if (result?.Principal is WindowsPrincipal wp)
    {
        // we will issue the external cookie and then redirect the
        // user back to the external callback, in essence, treating windows
        // auth the same as any other external authentication mechanism
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Callback"),
            Items =
    {
        { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
        { "scheme", "Windows" },
    }
        };

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity("Windows");

        // the sid is a good sub value
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, wp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid).Value));

        // the account name is the closest we have to a display name
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, wp.Identity.Name));

        // add the groups as claims -- be careful if the number of groups is too large
        var wi = wp.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

        // translate group SIDs to display names
        var groups = wi.Groups.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Value));
        id.AddClaims(roles);


        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(id),
            props);
        return Redirect(props.RedirectUri);
    }
    else
    {
        // trigger windows auth
        // since windows auth don't support the redirect uri,
        // this URL is re-triggered when we call challenge
        return Challenge("Windows");
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen, if everything goes well, is that the authentication happens automatically (without a login box?) because the "Challenge" call will require the client side (the browser) to send in Windows identity info and a token will be issued based on that.

It doesn't seem to work that way now - I am getting an Unauthorized error from API when starting the MVC app:

[image]

Am I doing that in the wrong place? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: What you observed (the prompt) is the actual Windows authentication, but not "an external login button Windows".

Comment: Thanks Lex. Just updated my post after some more test. Sorry about that.

Comment: What I expect to happen, if it works correctly, is that the authentication happens automatically (without a login box?) because the "Challenge" call will require the client side (the browser) to send in Windows identity info and a token will be issued based on that. Am I right about that? Or do I still get a login box and a login button?

Comment: Different browsers require different settings to suppress the prompt, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/troubleshoot/browsers/prompt-for-username-and-password

Comment: If I don't suppress the prompt, I should get a prompt, but that should be the browser's prompt, not the IdentityServer's login box, correct?

Comment: I read the document of IdentityServer 4, it says that "You trigger Windows authentication by calling ChallengeAsync on the Windows scheme (or if you want to use a constant: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
This will send the Www-Authenticate header back to the browser which will then re-load the current URL including the Windows identity " . So the correct challenge is triggering code to send www-authenticate to browser, browser gives a prompt to authenticate. The prompt is windows authentication's prompt.

Comment: So Bruce I just saw your comment now and thank you for your input! Yes, I did read that same document and if you look at the code I posted above, that's what I did (that's what I think I did, I should say). I am pretty sure I am not doing it correctly. I just don't know what I should do to correct it. The doc is soft of vague there.

Comment: @Alexu do you ever figure out how/where to trigger the Windows authentication? I'm currently stuck at where you were

Comment: @Farid I am not all the way through on Windows authentication yet but made some progress since this post. I now have the Windows button show up on the login page as an option for authentication. The main thing I missed was the call to services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme), which enables the Widnows authentication. I am still working on it though because I am still not able to get pass the windows login.